# Select multiple results on same row

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

It's about question results linked to customers, the table structure is as follow:

| customer ID | Question | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | A |
| 1 | 2 | B |
| 2 | 1 | A |
| 2 | 2 | D |

but I'm trying to make a query that would show one ligne per customer with all the results, like that :

| customer ID | Question ID 1 | Question ID 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | B |
| 2 | A | D |

Any idea how can I do that?

Comment: This is called pivoting.

Comment: Thanks, sounds great. Checking the syntax to make it work